# jQuery's $.ajax method does not work with JavaScript confirm() method

Tags: javascript, ajax, confirm

I am working on a basic **blog application** in Codeigniter 3.1.8 and Bootstrap 4.

The application has a delete post functionality. I got stuck at deleting posts via jQuery's `$.ajax` method.

The posts view looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm border-0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th class="w-50">Title</th>
      <th>Publication date</th>
      <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $index => $post): ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo $post->id; ?>">
      <td class="text-right"><?php $count = $index + 1; echo $count + $offset; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $post->title; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo nice_date($post->created_at, 'D, M d, Y'); ?></td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
          <a href="<?php echo base_url('posts/post/') . $post->id; ?>" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
          <?php if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') && $this->session->userdata('user_id') == $post->author_id) : ?>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url('posts/edit/') . $post->id; ?>" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit</a>
          <a href="#" id="delete_post" data-id="<?php echo $post->id ?>" class="ajax-btn btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>
          <?php else: ?>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success disabled"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit</a>
          <a href="#" id="delete_post" class="btn btn-success disabled"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The jQuery meant for delateing posts via $.ajax:

```
//Delete Posts
$('#delete_post').on('click', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var deleteUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    if(confirm('Delete this post?')) {
      if ($(this).hasClass("ajax-btn")) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'posts/delete/' + id,
          method: 'GET',
          dataType: 'html',
          success: function(deleteMsg){
            $('tr#' + id).fadeOut('250');
            $('#delete_msg').html('<p>Post successfully deleted</p>');
            $('#delete_msg').slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250);
          }
        });
      } else {
        window.location.href = deleteUrl;
      }
    }
```

});

The code above does not work for some reason. Where am I wrong?

Comment: For next time: "Does not work" makes the problem hard to understand. Do you not see the confirmation? See the confirmation but the post doesn't get deleted? Etc. Say what you're seeing, and what you expect/want instead. (In this case I think you're probably not seeing the confirmation when you click any but the first post's delete button.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have the same `id` on multiple elements. Instead, give your delete button a *class*:

```
<a href="#" id="delete_post" data-id="<?php echo $post->id ?>" class="delete-post ajax-btn btn btn-success">
```

...and then use `.delete_post` instead of `#delete_post`:

```
$('.delete_post').on('click', function(evt){
```